# How to push the set of records to the array for displaying dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Trying to load datatable with set of records, once table is loaded clicking on Pagination button(prev next) for triggering another set of records. Is it possible to merge first loading records(ex:300 records) and second loading records(ex:200 records) to the same array and display consolidated records(ex:500 records) in datatable ? Actually trying to implement pagination for large data sets, tried with diffrent approaches but no luck. so trying this way. Could you please suggest me how to get the consolidated records for every pagination button clicks.

Tried below code,

```
this.http.get(dataUrl,{params:params}).subscribe(response => {
      this.persons = response.data;
      this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = false));
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  }

  getAllrecords(){   
      var table = $('#firstTable').DataTable();
      var info = table.page.info();
      start = info.start;
      end=  info.pages;
      recordsTotal = info.recordsTotal+1;
      displayRecords = (recordsTotal+300)-1;

      this.loadTable();     
    }
```

[Working Demo for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-current-page-gbksnd)

Comment: Do you only want data of the page that is clicked? If I click on page 1 and then page 5 then the result should the consolidation data of page 1 and page 5 right?

Comment: Yes, correct...consolidated of all pages clicks.

Comment: "_Actually trying to implement pagination for large data sets_" - This can be handled using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). What did you try? And what problems did you encounter ("no luck")?

Comment: I am not sure why you would want or need to accumulate data in DataTables after each page selection. That is very different from implementing pagination for large data sets. It also makes basic actions such as sorting and searching impossible.

Comment: HI @andrewjames, Thanks for your reply, yes we tried the same thing like"Server side pagination" with POST call, data is populated but unfortunately datatable properties are not working like sort, search, pagination. Could you please clarify, what is the importance of "draw" key, do we need to send from UI to API ? and please help us like API itself do we need handle search, sort functionalities ? followed this link `https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way`.  Please suggest me..

Comment: "_datatable properties are not working like sort, search, pagination_": Did you implement those features in your server's data processing logic? The whole point of server-side is that in order to support very large data sets (thousands, millions of records), the _server_ does all the hard work. And the browser only receives the 10, 20, 100 records it needs to display to the user. Take another look at the link in my first comment.